# Javascript- How to make window.location to open selected values in a new page?

Tags: javascript

I have applied your solution like below but still not working. Any ideas? Thank you

**code**

```
open_links()
{
var options = document.querySelectorAll('#dwl option'); 
for( var i = 0 ; i < options.length ; i++ )
window.open(options[i].value, '_blank');
}

**HTML** 
<li id="li_8">
<label class="description" name="Download">Download a HTML sample</label>
<div>
<select id="dwl">
<option value="http://www.bbc.co.uk/">Sample 1</option>
<option value="http://www.bbc.co.uk/">Sample 2</option>
<option value="http://www.bbc.co.uk/">Sample 3</option>
<option value="http://www.bbc.co.uk/">Sample 4</option>
<option value="http://www.bbc.co.uk/">Sample 5</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="open_links()" value="Download" />
</div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.open(url, '_blank');`, to open all the link you should loop through all the options of select with id `dwl` using, you can use `document.querySelectorAll` for this :

**HTML :**

```
<input type="button" onclick="open_links()" value="Download" />
```

**JS :**

```
open_links()
{
    var options = document.querySelectorAll('#dwl option'); 
    for( var i = 0 ; i < options.length ; i++ )
        window.open(options[i].value, '_blank');
}
```

Hope this helps.